# Using eigen loadMarket function to load Matrix from a file is very slow

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I want to compute Sparse Matrix and I have used saveMarket(A, "A.mtx") to store the result of my matrix. It's about 2.65 GB.

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, Eigen::RowMajor> SMatrixXf;
SMatrixXf A;
// some other processing here
A = A.transpose();
saveMarket(A, "A.mtx");
```

I want to use this matrix in another program. But it turns out it would take 137s to load this matrix.

```
loadMarket(A, "A.mtx");
```

Any idea to speed up the loading process?
Or is there other way to store and load the Matrix?
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have edited the question.

Comment: You can try to store the memory of `valuePtr()`, `innerIndexPtr()`, and `outerIndexPtr()` directly to a file. This can be loaded very fast by memory-mapping the file and building a `Map<SparseMatrix<...> >` using that data. (Time to access the matrix depends on how fast your OS can transfer data from your storage device to RAM).

Comment: Thank you! I would have a try!

Comment: As chtz suggested, storing your data in binary format will be one or two orders of magnitude faster.